# Extracting the greatest value from a time series in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgresql database with a column for timestamp, and a column for reading.  I have several readings per second.  I'd like to return the highest reading for any given second.  I have a query to extract the timestamp in the format I like, and to extract the power, but I'm not sure how to filter to get the highest power reading.

For example:

```
[ts1 second = 5]  [reading = 3]
[ts2 second = 5]  [reading = 5]
```

I'd like a query to return `[ts2 second = 5] [reading = 5]`, for every unique second in the column.

Part of my issue is that the timestamps include milliseconds, and I want to be unique by second.

Comment: This seems like a plain use of max, group by and order by. What is your difficult? What have you tried?

Comment: @JorgeCampos - I'm relieved to know it's easy, thanks.  I'm still experimenting.  I've only used basic queries in Postgresql so far, so this is advanced for me :)

Comment: It would be like: `select second, max(reading) from yourtable group by second limit 1` there is no need for a order...

Comment: Show us db schema and some sample data. You say millisecond, but your data only show seconds Also show us your current query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT "ts2 second" , MAX("reading")
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY "ts2 second"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select second, 
       max(reading) 
  from yourtable 
 group by second 
 limit 1
```

`limit 1` is to get only one result.